# SQL Server and XML query

Tags: sql-server, xml

Suddenly I cannot find the right way or hint to the solution anywhere, so trying there:

I have a select like this:

```
declare @XmlOutput xml 
set @XmlOutput = (
SELECT
           R.ID
          ,R.[PN] as 'Nummer'
          ,R.[TitlePrefixAbbreviation] as Title 
          ,R.[FirstName]
          ,R.LastName
          ,RA.[DescriptiveNumber]
          ,RA.[OrientationalNumber]
          ,RC.Contact  
      FROM [tbl1] as R
      left join tbl2 as RA on R.ID = RA.[RID] 
      left join [tbl3 as RC on R.ID = RC.[RID] 
      for xml auto, ROOT('mbox'), ELEMENTS
)
select @XmlOutput
```

and the result looks like this:

```
<mbox>
  <R>
    <ID>66284</ID>
    <Nummer>999999</Nummer>
    <Title />
    <FirstName>test</FirstName>
    <LastName>test</LastName>
    <RA>
      <HouseNr>9999</HouseNr>
      <SequenceNr />
      <City>London</City>
      <ZIP>99999</ZIP>
      <RC>
        <Contact>letitroll@gmail.com</Contact>
      </RC>
    </RA>
  </R>
  <mbox>
```

As you can see, there are hierarchy elements `RA, R, RC` that depend on joining tables.

And I cannot find out how to make the XML only with root element `<mbox>` and without sub tree like `R, RC, RA`

Something like this ->

```
<mbox>
    <ID>66284</ID>
    <Nummer>999999</Nummer>
    <Title />
    <FirstName>Štěpánka</FirstName>
    <LastName>Solomková</LastName>
    <HouseNr>2015</HouseNr>
    <SequenceNr />
    <City>London</City>
    <ZIP>99999</ZIP>
    <Contact>letitroll@gmail.com</Contact>  
<mbox>
```

I think about a workaround by using temporary table, where i firstly put all selected data, and the generate XML from TMP table, but I hope that there is more elegant way.

Can somebody help ?

Bests,
gelo

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @XmlOutput xml 
set @XmlOutput = (
Select * from
(
SELECT
           R.ID
          ,R.[PN] as 'Nummer'
          ,R.[TitlePrefixAbbreviation] as Title 
          ,R.[FirstName]
          ,R.LastName
          ,RA.[DescriptiveNumber]
          ,RA.[OrientationalNumber]
          ,RC.Contact  
      FROM [tbl1] as R
      left join tbl2 as RA on R.ID = RA.[RID] 
      left join [tbl3 as RC on R.ID = RC.[RID] 
) mbox
      for xml auto,  ELEMENTS
)
select @XmlOutput
```

Comment: thank you, very cool and easy solution. Will grow up my sql skills ;)